# Application crashes when closing a window

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, titanium

I'm using Titanium version 2.1.3.GA to build an iOS application. Target iOS 6.0

Basically when a user clicks a task, they can edit it. Then save it. Once I save it I go to close the edit windown with`me.win.close();` but, as soon as it hits that line... it crashes with nothing in my debugger except "Application has exited from simulator".

I commented that out to make sure that was it. It will also do the same thing if I force them to use the cancel button as it is the same `me.win.close();`

This is not the only window open so I know it's not me closing the root window.

I have no clue why this is happening and ANY help would be appreciated.

Edit - here's the cancel method

```
this.btnCancelOnClicked = function() {
    me.clientData = null;
    me.win.close();
};
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Everything else goes successfully. It's only the `win.close();` that's jacking up. But I will edit with the cancel button method

Comment: Can you tell me what does "me" means? Does it means to current window?

Comment: `me = this;` is how `me` is created

Comment: Does it means the current window?

Comment: Yes. I've also check to make sure by doing `alert(me.win.title);` which gives me the title of the window that it's about to close.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19571/discussion-between-nandu-and-brogers)

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample application very similar to yours. Just try this

```
var wndHome = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     backgroundColor : 'white'
});

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
 top : 0
});

var tabledata = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
 var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
  title : 'Didn\'t clicked yet'
 });
 tabledata.push(row);
}
tableView.data = tabledata;
wndHome.add(tableView);
wndHome.open();


tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 var title;
 var wndNewWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor : '#999966'
 });

 var textbox = Ti.UI.createTextField({
  top : '20%',
  width : '75%',
  height : '55',
  borderColor : 'white',
  borderRadius : 10,
  color   : 'red',
  backgroundColor : 'white',
  hintText : 'Type your message'
 });
 var btnWrite = Ti.UI.createButton({
  title : 'Save',
  top   : '40%',
  width : 'auto'
 });

 wndNewWindow.add(textbox);
 wndNewWindow.add(btnWrite);
 wndNewWindow.open();
 btnWrite.addEventListener('click', function(){
  title = textbox.value;
  wndNewWindow.close();
 });
 wndNewWindow.addEventListener('close', function(){
  e.rowData.title = title;
 });
});
```

Comment: This looks like it would work. I have to change about 30 things to implement this (I have to change everything from `this.win` to my new window variable). I will post something about this soon. Thank you all of your effort.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. However, I do have a slightly more complicated dealio going on.